# How would I alter a list within a list in Scala using functional programming

Tags: scala

Imagine I have a `list[list[object]]`
and I wanted to get a `list[list[object.field]]`

How would i be able to do this through functional programming

as in
if `val list = list[list[object]]`
i tried

```
val newList = list(_)(_1.map(object.field))
```

but this gave me an error and I am confused

I just started functional programming and scala so there might be something completely illogical with this statement

Comment: What is `list(_)` supposed to mean?  And what is `_1` ? Once you get past these two, the compiler error message should become more informative.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `map` as following

```
  case class Obj(field: String)
  val list = List[List[Obj]]()

  val fields: List[List[String]] = list.map(_.map(_.field))
```

or same as

```
  val fields: List[List[String]] = list.map(innerList => innerList.map(obj => obj.field))
```

or if you want to have a flattened list of fields

```
  val fields: List[String] = list.flatMap(_.map(_.field))
```